# Is an irregular language concatenated with a language with which it has no common symbols irregular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. Suppose I have a languages
$$
L_{1} = \{a^ib^i \mid  i>0\},\\
L_{2} = \{c^i \mid i>0\}
$$

and
$$
L_{1}L_{2} = \{a^ib^ic^i \mid i>0\}
$$

Is it true that if $L_{1}$ is irregular and $L_{1}$ has no common symbols with $L_{2}$, then $L_{1}L_{2}$ is irregular? How would you prove this?

Comment: Your $L_1 L_2$ should be $\{a^i b^i c^j \mid i > 0 \wedge j > 0\}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your $L1L2$ is wrong. $$L1L2 = \{a^ib^ic^j\ | \ i>0, j>0\}$$
Your conclusion is right, $L1L2$ is irregular(as long as $L2\neq\phi$, otherwise  $L1L2=\phi$ is clearly regular). This can be proved using [Myhill–Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Suppose $X$,$Y$ are any 2 different equivalence classes of $R_{L1}$, $x\in X, y\in Y$, then there exists string $z$ such that $xz \in L1$ while $yz \notin L1$.

If $L2=\{\epsilon\}$, then $L1L2$=$L1$ is irregular. Otherwise, take any string $w\in L2, w \neq \epsilon$, then $xzw \in L1L2$, but $yzw\notin L1L2$ 
(consider that, due to no common symbol, no suffix of $yzw$ longer  than $|w|$ in L2, and no prefix of $yzw$ shorter than $|yz|$ in $L1$).

This shows that $x$,$y$ belongs to different equivalence classes of $R_{L1L2}$, too. ie. there must be at least the same number of equivalence classes in $R_{L1L2}$ as in $R_{L1}$

From Myhill–Nerode theorem, $L1$ has infinite number of equivalence classes. Thus $L1L2$ also has infinite number of equivalence classes, which means $L1L2$ is irregular also.

Comment: if $L2=\emptyset$ then $L1L2=\emptyset$. Or did you mean something else by $\phi$?

Comment: @RanG. corrected in answer. $L2=\phi$ is a special case that $L1L2=\phi$ is regular.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Better use `\emptyset` for $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 8):

Yes: in general, if $L_1$ is a non-regular language over alphabet $\Sigma_1$, and $L_2$ is a language over some other alphabet $\Sigma_2$ with no symbols in common (i.e., $\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2 = \emptyset$), and if $L_2$ is not the empty language ($L_2 \ne \emptyset$), then the language $L_1 L_2$ is also non-regular.

This follows from the [closure properties of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties).  In particular, if $L$ is a regular language and $f$ is a [string homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_operations#String_homomorphism), then $f(L)$ (the homomorphic image of $L$ under $f$) is also regular.  Now suppose $L_1 L_2$ was regular.  Notice that

$$L_1 = f(L_1 L_2)$$

where $f$ is defined so that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in \Sigma_1$ and $f(x)=\varepsilon$ for all $x \in \Sigma_2$.  (This is a string homomorphism.)

So, by the closure property, if $L_1 L_2$ was regular, it would follow that $L_1$ was regular as well -- contradicting our assumption.  The only possible conclusion is that if $L_1$ is not regular, then $L_1 L_2$ is not regular, either.

Comment: if $\epsilon \notin L_2$, then $L_1L_2\cap \Sigma_1^*=\phi\neq L_1$

Comment: @TerenceHang, thank you!  I've corrected my answer; it should no longer have that issue.  I should have used a string homomorphism from the start, rather than intersection.

Answer (score 5):

The nit-picking answer is actually NO, the language $L_1L_2$ is not necessarily nonregular. In order for the given proofs to work we have to require that $L_2\neq \varnothing$, since $L_1\varnothing = \varnothing$ which is regular.

The machinery given in the other answers (Myhill-Nerode and closure properties) is really useful and in general is preferable over ad hoc methods. Here however there is a very elegant (albeit ad hoc) construction. If we have a finite automaton for $L_1L_2$ and letters in the languages are disjoint, then we simply can replace all letters from $L_2$ by the empty string $\varepsilon$ and we get an automaton with $\varepsilon$-transitions for $L_1$. Assuming of course that $L_2\neq\varnothing$!

For this to work we only need to know that  automata with $\varepsilon$-transitions are also defining regular languages.